# Importing a Term Document Matrix in CSV format into R

Tags: r, csv, text-mining, text-analysis

So I already have a TDM but it was on excel. So I saved it as CSV. Now I want to do some analysis but I can´t load it as a TDM using tm package. My CSV looks something like this:

```
           item01    item02    item03     item04


red         0          1         1           0
circle      1          0         0           1
fame        1          0         0           0
yellow      0          0         1           1 
square      1          0         1           0
```

So I haven't been able to load that file as a TDM, the best I've tried so far is this :

```
myDTM <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(df, weighting = weightBin)
```

But it loads 1's on all cells

```
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 2529, terms: 1952)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 4936608/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 27
Weighting          : binary (bin)
Sample             :

             Terms
Docs            item01 item02 item03 item04
      Red        1        1     1       1                
      Circle     1        1     1       1          
      fame       1        1     1       1
```

I've tried converting first to Corpus and other things but if i try to use any function like inspect(tdm) it returns an error, like this or similar.

```
Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(x, docs, terms) :
```

I really don´t believe there isn't a way to import it in the right format, any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first converting the CSV to a sparse matrix.  My CSV is different from yours because I typed it myself, but it's the same idea.

```
> library(tm)
> library(Matrix)
> myDF <- read.csv("my.csv",row.names=1,colClasses=c('character',rep('integer',4)))
> mySM <- Matrix(as.matrix(myDF),sparse=TRUE)
> myDTM <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(mySM,weighting = weightBin)
> inspect(myDTM)

<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 5, terms: 4)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 7/13
Sparsity           : 65%
Maximal term length: 6
Weighting          : binary (bin)
Sample             :
        Terms
Docs     item01 item02 item03 item04
  circle      1      1      0      0
  fame        1      0      0      0
  red         0      0      0      0
  square      1      0      1      0
  yellow      0      0      1      1 
>
```